# How to recover a KeyedStream from different filters applied after been keyed before

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

How can I spread out the same keyedStream and apply filters according to different uses cases without the need to create a new keyedStream at the end of the filtering?
Example:

```
DataStream<Event> streamFiltered = RabbitMQConnector.eventStreamObject(env)
                .flatMap(new Consumer())
                .name("Event Mapper")
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new PeriodicExtractor())
                .name("Watermarks Added")
                .filter(new NullIdEventsFilterFunction())
                .name("Event Filter");

/*now I will or need to send the same keyedStream for applying two different transformations with different filters but under the same keyed concept*/

/*Once I'd applied the filter I will receive back a SingleOutputStreamOperator and then I need to keyBy again*/
/*in a normal scenario I will need to do keyBy again, and I want to avoid that */

KeyedStream<T,T> keyed1 = streamFiltered.filter(x -> x.id != null).keyBy(key -> key.id); /*wants to avoid this*/
KeyedStream<T,T> keyed2= streamFiltered.filter(x -> x.id.lenght > 10).keyBy(key -> key.id);/*wants to avoid this*/

seeProduct(keyed1);
checkProduct(keyed2);

/*these are just an example, this two operations receive a keyedStream under the same concept but with different filters applied to the keyedStream already created and wants to reuse that same keyedStream after different filters to avoid a new creation*/
private static SingleOutputStreamOperator<EventProduct>seeProduct(KeyedStream<Event, String> stream) {
        return stream.map(x -> new EventProduct(x)).name("Event Product");
    }

private static SingleOutputStreamOperator<EventCheck>checkProduct(KeyedStream<Event, String> stream) {
        return stream.map(x -> new EventCheck(x)).name("Event Check");
    }
```

in a normal scenario every single filter function will return a SingleOutputStream and then I need to do keyBy again (but I already has a keyedStream by id which is the idea, to get this after a filter I will need to do key by again and create a new KeyedStream). There is any how to keep the keyedStream concept after applying a filter for example?

Comment: BTW, the term "broadcast" has a specific technical meaning in Flink which doesn't seem to apply here.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your case the `side output` feature will help - you can have a separate side output from a base `keyed stream` for each filter scenario.

Please, see more details and examples at flink side outputs documentation: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html.

Something like this (in pseudocode) should work for you:

```java
final OutputTag<Tuple2<String, Event>> outputTag1 = new OutputTag<>("side-output-filter-1"){};
final OutputTag<Tuple2<String, Event>> outputTag2 = new OutputTag<>("side-output-filter-2"){};
DataStream<Event> keyedStream = source.keyby(x -> x.id);
     .process(new KeyedProcessFunction<Tuple, Tuple2<String, Event>, Tuple2<String, Event>> {
     @Override
      public void processElement(
          Tuple2<String, Event> value,
          Context ctx,
          Collector<Tuple2<String, Event>> out) throws Exception {
        // emit data to regular output
        out.collect(value);

        // emit data to side output
        ctx.output(outputTag1, value);
        ctx.output(outputTag2, value);
      }
})
/*for use case one I need to use the same keyed concept but apply a filter*/
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Event>> sideOutputStream1 = keyedStream.getSideOutput(outputTag1).filter(x -> x.id != null);

/*for use case two I need to use the same keyed concept but apply a filter*/
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Event>> sideOutputStream2 = keyedStream.getSideOutput(outputTag2).filter(x -> x.id.lenght > 10);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but using this method I will need to create a new `keyedStream` after getting the DataStream, and the main idea is to avoid creating a new `KeyedStream` when I already has one, just need to refilter it and continue using the same `keyedStream` without create a new one. Thanks a lot one more  time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the simplest answer would be to first apply the filtering, and then use keyBy.

If for some reason you need to key partition the stream before filtering (e.g., you might be applying a RichFilterFunction that uses key-partitioned state), then you could use [reinterpretAsKeyedStream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/experimental.html) to re-establish the keying without the expense of another keyBy.

Using side outputs is a good way split a stream into several filtered sub-streams, but once again those output streams will not be KeyedStreams. You can only safely use reinterpretAsKeyedStream if reapplying the key selector function would produce exactly the same partitioning that's already in place.

Comment: Hi one more time @David, I will try this method, I'd like how it sounds. Kind regards.

Comment: I still don't understand why the initial keyBy is useful -- can't you just get rid of it?

Comment: I need to use the same keyedStream by id in more than one use case in my job, that's why I create it right after the filter and then send it to the operators, but these use cases that used the same keyed concept has different filters to apply, so I can filter first and then create a new keyedstream under the same concept for each use case (current way), but I'm asking if exist another solution to filter a keyedStream and then use it as keyed stream again without the need to keyby again. Example bellow

Comment: I want to avoid this:
`DataStream<Event> streamFiltered = stream.filter(x -> x.id != null);  
 Keyed1<T,T> k1 = stream.filter(concept).keyby(x -> x.id);   
Keyed1<T,T> k2 = stream.filter(concept2).keyby(x -> x.id);   
 Keyed1<T,T> k3 = stream.filter(concept3).keyby(x -> x.id);`  
 as you can see I'm creating a new keyedstream for each filter, I'm asking if there exist away to create that keyedStream just once and reuse it as much as possible when applying various filters are needed without need to do `keyby()` again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't really advise on this without knowing what the rest of the job graph looks like (after the filtering and mapping), and why you need a KeyedStream. reinterpretAsKeyedStream is the answer to your question of how to do the keying before the filtering, and avoid doing it again. But "reusing" the stream may not have any performance benefit -- what matters is what the resulting execution graph looks like, or in other words, how many times each record goes through ser/de, and how many times each record has to be sent over the network.

Comment: I need that KeyedStream because I have some use cases (down at the job graph) where sent the records with the same id to apply some computation and to be sure that when I call `state.value()` will always return the same key is required, but in some of those use cases the keyed concept and filtering is the same `(id != null)`, but in some others the keyed concept is the same but the filter is different `(id.equals(1))`;